Как правильно применять css стили из файлов к разным сраницам?
Для каждой страницы сделан свой файл с css стилями, при подключении одного файла к странице применются стили из другого файла, который к этой странице не подключался  

Все селекторы имеют "единую видимость". Т.ч. считай, что ты их написал в одном файле...
